# retrieve byte from 32 bit integer using bitwise operators

Tags: c

Here is the problem and what I currently have, I just don't understand how it is wrong...

> getByte - Extract byte n from word x    Bytes numbered from 0 (LSB) to
>   3 (MSB)    Examples: getByte(0x12345678,1) = 0x56    Legal ops: ! ~ &
>   ^ | + << >>    Max ops: 6    Rating: 2

```
int getByte(int x, int n) {
  return ((x << (24 - 8 * n)) >> (8 * n));
}
```

Comment: this is the error i get: ERROR: Test getByte(-2147483648[0x80000000],3[0x3]) failed...
...Gives -128[0xffffff80]. Should be 128[0x80]

Comment: It's wrong in terms of usage of illegal operators. the `-` operator is not listed under "Legal ops"

Comment: i see that now but regardless, the test program doesn't test for legality of operators

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your shifting doesn't make any sense - first, you shift left by (24 - 8n) bits, then you shift back right by 8n bits. Why? Also, it's wrong. If n is 0, you shift x left by 24 bits and return that value. Try pen and paper to see that this is entirely wrong.

The correct approach would be to do:

```
int getByte(int x, int n) {
  return (x >> 8*n) & 0xFF;
}
```

Comment: this makes much more sense thank you, once i used pen and paper to see where i made the mistake it was perfect

Comment: Also, you can only shift to the register size (32 on 32-bit, 64 or 64-bit). Otherwise, its undefined behavior. So `getByte(0xffffffff, 16)` would lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Unless i am totally mistaken, your code is mathematically incorrect.

```
getByte(0x000000ff, 0) {
    24 - 8 * n = 24;
    8 * n = 0;
    0x000000ff << 24 = 0xff000000;
    0xff000000 >> 0 = 0xff000000;
    return 0xff000000; // should return 0xff
}
```

Not being allowed to use operators `-` and especially `*` is a problem (can't do `* 8`). I came up with this:

```
uint8_t getByte (uint32_t x, int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            return x & 0xff;
        case 1:
            return (x >> 8) & 0xff;
        case 2:
            return (x >> 16) & 0xff;
        case 3:
            return x >> 24;
    }
}
```

Not exactly beautiful, but it conforms to the problem description: 6 operators, all of them legal.

EDIT: Just had a (pretty obvious) idea for how to avoid `* 8`

```
uint8_t getByte (uint32_t x, int n) {
    return (x >> (n << 3)) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Yes--performing a left shift is equivalent to multiplication by 2.  So shifting left 3 times is 2^3 = 8.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as it avoids "illegal" operations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how your function works. Try this instead:

```
int getByte(int x, int n)
{
     return (x >> (8 * n)) & 0xFF;
}
```