# How to convert float to bytes in little-endian format in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

How can I convert a float to bytes **in little-endian format**?

like

```
5.05 -> \x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x14\x40
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
# let v = Int64.bits_of_float 5.05 in
  for i = 0 to 7 do
    Printf.printf "%Lx " (Int64.logand 255L (Int64.shift_right v (i*8))) ;
  done 
  ;;
33 33 33 33 33 33 14 40 - : unit = ()
```

Comment: I wish there were an efficient primitive for that.

Comment: how can I get a byte array from this?

Comment: @MartinJambon If efficiency is a concern, a short C function could do everything in a single allocation (that of the result, say a `string`). My solution allocates, on a 64-bit architecture, 17 blocks of two words each including the header: `v`, 8 shifted partial results, and 8 loganded ones. Not nice, but not not something you would really notice either unless your program spends its time accessing bytes of floats.

Comment: @JacksonTale Explain to me what a “byte array” is in OCaml and I will tell you how to get one. Or better yet, leave me out of it altogether, explain to OCaml what a byte array is, and fill it with the values that are successively passed to `Printf.printf "%Lx "`.

Comment: @JacksonTale “Why do we use `shift_right` and `logand` operations when portably extracting bytes in little-endian order from an integer?” That is another question than the one you originally asked. You could ask it on StackOverflow. Do not forget to first check whether it has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132706/retrieve-byte-from-32-bit-integer-using-bitwise-operators

Comment: thanks for your answer, let me rephrase my question. How can I write the lowest 8 bit of an int64 into a char?

Comment: `Char.chr (Int64.to_int 32L)` to get `' '`